# ALTER TABLE xxx RENAME TO xxxx; success, but the table name did not change in the navicat

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I execute this line SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE dinnertable RENAME TO dinnerTable;
```

And in the info console:

> [SQL] ALTER TABLE dinnertable RENAME TO dinnerTable;
>   受影响的行: 0
>   时间: 0.001s

But in the navicat, you see below, the table name did not change:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Did you refresh in Navicat? Right-click -> Refresh or just re-open connection

Comment: @YossiVainshtein, off cource I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_rename 'old_table_name','new_table_name';
```

Comment: just refresh ur navigat

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have refreshed the navicat. So this problem can be a mysql table name case sensitive setting problem. Please check the *my.cnf* or *my.ini* file of this mysql case. Change the parameter named *lower_case_tables_name*. If you don't find it you need to add

```
lower_case_tables_name = 0
```

below [mysqld]
Then restart the mysql case.

Comment: @www.tonitexh.com的站长, I refreshed it, not this cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by adding double quotes to your rename statement.

```
ALTER TABLE "dinnertable" RENAME TO "dinnerTable";
```

- This could be refresh problem.
  Please close the database connection or connect once again
- Case sensitivity problem. Please try by adding double quotes.
- **Update** Export table along with data using any of modern IDE's and import the same by updating the table name.

**Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive**. 
(Please note this is for Oracle, not sure about mysql)
Oracle interprets them as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

By enclosing names in double quotation marks, you can give the following names to different objects in the same namespace:

```
"employees"
"Employees"
"EMPLOYEES"
```

Refer to the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) for more information.

Comment: ， If I use double quotes, I will get error:`[SQL] ALTER TABLE "dinnertable" RENAME TO "dinnerTable";
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"dinnertable" RENAME TO "dinnerTable"' at line 1`

Comment: This statement is specific to Oracle database. Not sure for MySql. Could you please try with single quote instead of double quote.

Comment: Backticks for mysql.(`)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: If still not works then please export the table with create statement along with data and import once again by changing the table name. Export will be available in many IDE's like PL/SQL Developer etc

Comment: @GrabNewTech I tested too.

Comment: @lustre Have you tried all options 1. single quote, 2. Backticks 3. export/imports ?

Comment: @GrabNewTech what mean of  3. export/imports?

Comment: @lustre This is workaround option. 1. Export -> Export the table with create table statement along with data (This can be done using any of the existing IDE's eg: PL/SQL developer) 2. Update the table name as per your need in the exported script. 3. Drop the existing table. 4. Create table along with data using the exported script